# Highcharts change symbol and hover text of individual points Line Chart

Tags: highcharts

In reference to this example:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

How would one change the symbols for  the individual points and put custom hover over text for each individual point, when our series is structured exactly like in this example? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are several individual examples which should cover your topics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just solved it using this code here: http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/markers-with-x-y-data-series-t9232/

Answer (score 1):

Solved using [this](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/markers-with-x-y-data-series-t9232/) code.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    defaultSeriesType: 'line'
},
series: [{
    data: [{x:1.0,y:209.9,marker: {symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'}}, {x:4.0,y:71.5}]
}]
});
```